# In Javascript, how do I loop through instiating objects but keep addEventlistener active on past instances?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to create a set of flask/python/javascript classes so that I can create different dynamic drop menus from the same javascrip file.

I also want it to run dynamic drop down menus of different depth levels (eg select oem -> select model, oem select -> select model-> select serial_number).

My code is responsive for a two level menu but not a three level menu.  I try to instantiate the class using a for loop with variables from an array.  It looks like as the for loop iterates it wipes out the past instant and replaces it.  Here is my Javascript file, the loop is at the bottom.

If this is the problem, how can I resolve this?

```
// TODO add further description

const list = [];
for (let key of Object.keys(drop_down_categories)) {
  //console.log(drop_down_categories[key])
  list.push(drop_down_categories[key]);
}

class MenuSelection {
  constructor(filter, result, list_num) {
    this.filter = filter;
    this.result = result;
    this.list_num = list_num;
  }

  startListener() {
    this.filter.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      console.log(this.filter);
      let input = '../filter_selection//' + e.target.value + '//' + list_num;
      console.log(input);
      this.getIt(input);
    });
  }

  async getIt(input) {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(input);
      console.log(res.data);
      let optionHTML = '';
      for (let item of res.data.filtered_selection) {
        optionHTML += '<option value="' + item.label + '">' + item.label + < /option>';
      }
      console.log(this.result)
      this.result.innerHTML = optionHTML;

    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Could not reach endpoint filter_selection')
      console.log(err);
    };
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
  filterCriteria = document.getElementById(list[(i)]);
  filteredResult = document.getElementById(list[(i + 1)]);
  list_num = list[i];
  const test = new MenuSelection(filterCriteria, filteredResult, list_num);
  test.startListener();
}
```

Python Endpoint and related classes

```
from flask import jsonify
from app.models import ModelName
from . import db_queries


class FilterSelection:
    def __init__(self, input, drop_down_type):
        self.input = input
        self.drop_down_type = drop_down_type
        print(self.drop_down_type)
        self.query = None
        self.sql_column = None

    def filter_selection(self):
        # need to replace %20(blank space) in variable, caused by encoding
        self.input = self.input.replace("%20", " ")

        if self.drop_down_type == "oem":
            self.query = ModelName.query.filter_by(oem=self.input).all()
            self.sql_column = "model_name"

        if self.drop_down_type == "model_name":
            self.query = ModelName.query.filter_by(model_name=self.input).all()
            self.sql_column = "serial_number"

        return self.make_JSON()

    def make_JSON(self):
        Array = []
        for i in self.query:
            Obj = {}
            Obj['label'] = getattr(i, self.sql_column)
            Array.append(Obj)
        print(Array)
        return jsonify({'filtered_selection': Array})


@db_queries.route('/filter_selection/<input>/<drop_down_type>')
def filter_selection(input, drop_down_type):
    """
    # TODO add further description
    This route uses the filter selection class
    """
    selection = FilterSelection(input, drop_down_type)
    return selection.filter_selection()
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable. We don't need the AJAX call, you can use hard-coded data to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I will post it soon.